# Fix Problem With Textdomain Translation

Tags: translation, textdomain

I translate some text with textdomain:

```
_e( 'My Text', 'my-text-domain' );
```

And I am using Loco Translate plugin. It was working fine, but now it has stopped working.

What is the best way to find the problem why it`s not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the file style.css is written:

```
Text Domain: my-text-domain
```

Check that is activated in the template files:

```
load_theme_textdomain('my-text-domain');
```